# how can iuse jquery ui resizable in for loop

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using JqueryUI-resizable for one table. The table structure is getting generated by some external plugin, which gives table header and table body in different divs..

To make the columns resiable I am using:

```
 $(".table-header .table th:eq(2)" ).resizable({
         minWidth: 70,
         alsoResize: ".table-container .table td:eq(2)"
     });
```

This works fine. The issue is now the table column number is going to be dynamic.. there can be 'n' numbers of columns. How can i get this in for loop?

```
  var colCount=$(".table-container .table-bordered th").size();
        for (i = 2; i < colCount; i++) { 

       $(".table-header .table th:eq("+i+")" ).resizable({
                 minWidth: 70,
                 alsoResize: ".table-container .table td:eq("+i+")"
             });
    }
```

i am not getting how to do that, can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `.each()` like so:

```
$(".table-container .table-bordered th").each(function(i, el){
  if(i > 1){
    $(el).resizable({
      minWidth: 70,
      alsoResize: ".table-container .table td:eq(" + i + ")"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer.. it really helped me.. only difference i made is i just took the count number through: var colNum=$(this).index();

Comment: @ShrutiJog glad to hear this helped. If it did, you may want to upvote or mark it as the answer.